# Customize Facebook dialog feed in android is not working

Tags: android, facebook, dialog

I want to share the customize message from my android device to facebook.  To customize the facebook feed i am using the code which i have given below.  I was wondering that is there is problem with my code or problem with facebook dialog box.

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("caption", "Check out this Image :");
    parameters.putString("name","Information");
    parameters.putString("description", "This is nice App");
    parameters.putString("message", "This is cool..");
    facebook.dialog(FBConnect.this, "feed", parameters, new FBPostedToWallListener());
```

Thanks for the help in advance,  aby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems was with one of the classes now it is Solved!!